# Display HTML data on a page : corona SDK

Tags: android, html, coronasdk

In one of my apps in corona, I have to display a html table in a scene. Is it possible to display a html table(whose html data string is generated within the app) on a normal page of corona sdk app..?

Any advice is appreciable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking, and if so, then yes, of course you can!

What you need to do is use the API for WebView.

*Note: Native web views are only supported on Android, iOS, the Corona Simulator for OS X, and OS X desktop apps. [see documentation here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/newWebView.html)*

You can load local or remote html files using this API.

```
local webView = native.newWebView( 0, 0, 320, 480 )
webView:request( "http://www.coronalabs.com/" )
-- or
webView:request( "localfile.html", system.ResourceDirectory )
```

I have done this quite a few times in a medical app I was developing, where I would link customers to medical products directly from my app, and then when they were finished browsing, they could close out the webview and continue using the app as normal.

If you desire similar functionality to this, all you need to do is set up your webview, and create a overlay with some kind of back button the user can press to kill the webview, which should be fairly explanatory from the API.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But, this native webview is loading the data from a local html page na? I don't want that. Because my html string is generated within a game scene, and I want to directly display the html string as viewable table on the scene.

Comment: Ah I see, that is where I was misunderstanding you. I haven't had to do such a thing before, but perhaps you could take your html string data, and save it as a local html file, and then launch it? I am still a little unclear of what you are trying to do, but if you are just trying to generate a html table from inside your game, I don't see why you can't just save the html string first, and then load the html file you just created. Sorry again if I can't provide an exact answer. :(

Comment: Krs, why don't you just save your dynamically generated html string to html file in caches directory and then use JoeyMaru's answer to show it?