# corona sdk html layout view that works in Simulator for help/doco presentation?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

What's the best way to display formatted static content to a user in Corona SDK?  For example for your help page.  So my specific requirements are:

1. needs to support Simulator (to iterate during development and
   seeing layout)
2. support passing a string variable with HTML (i.e.
   doesn't need to be a file or a www url)
3. be placed within a
   newScrollView to be scrollable

Anything available to do this?

Background:

- The newWebView doesn't seem to support the above hence my question.    I get this on my Mac when building the WebViewPhysics sample project.
- native.newWebView() does not work in the Corona Simulator. Please build for device (or Xcode simulator) for this sample to work properly.
- Wanted to avoid having to use multiple newText() type elements, then having to reposition them etc.  The content will have some static and dynamic components to it.
- Also using HTML would make it useful to be able to the email the page too (e.g. like a report).

Comment: 1. Can you explain why saving to a local file is not suitable? Like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176729/display-html-data-on-a-page-corona-sdk? 2. Also have you looked at textcandy (no html, but html might no longer be required if yo use that)?

Comment: dynamic view - so will have elements of the text (e.g. currency) being updates multiples times a second, as other UI elements are moved around.  Have text candy & widget candy and already looked at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of such thing, hopefully someone else does, but here are some ideas to consider:

- Interpreting HTML string is pretty heavy compute compared to displaying a plain text, asking corona app to do this many times a second, for full HTML string even if just one character chagnes, may cause flickering, assuming such component even exists.
- Two options that I see:

  1. Create a multi-text display group where each member is one line, and each line is a group of display text objects. Then only update the text objects that change.
  2. Create a mini local web server in your corona app, would just have to open a socket and listen for HTTP get then push data to the "client" javascript (running in the native webviewer in your corona app). This is a bit twisted, admittedly.

Comment: I'm starting the think your option 1 might end up being the only way to go.  I was thinking of a library function where you specify your data, then ask for it as either a Display Group (for display on a page) or as HTML (for inclusion in an email).  So effectively biting the bullet and produced two separate "views" of the report depending on where it is going to end up.  What do you think @Schollii?

Comment: @Greg makes a lot of sense